# How do I create an empty op_array?

Tags: php, c, opcode, php-internals

In my PHP extension, how can I create an op_array with no opcodes in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use init_op_array(), declared in from zend_compile.h:

```
zend_op_array * op_array = emalloc(sizeof(zend_op_array));
init_op_array(op_array, type, INITIAL_OP_ARRAY_SIZE TSRMLS_CC);
```

type can be ZEND_EVAL_CODE or ZEND_USER_FUNCTION.